# How can I dump an entire assembly to source files using reflector?

Tags: .net, reflector, disassembly

Is there a way to dump an entire assemblies source to files using reflector?

Answer (score 4):

I have had great luck with the [FileDisassembler](http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx) plug-in.

Comment: 1+: I'll second that. Very handy link :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, right click on the assembly and choose Export...